# Any neat and quick way to kill a process including all child processes

Tags: linux, shell, process, kill

I know this sounds like a common question and I should be able to find answer in archives. Tried looking for some, but couldn't find. All the responses look very lengthy. Any 1-liner to kill a process in linux including all its children processes.

Comment: Visit [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618403/how-to-kill-all-subprocesses-of-shell), it should help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they're all in the same group, use `kill` and pass the negation of the group id, as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392155/179138).

Answer (score 2):

```
kill $PID $(pgrep -P $PID)
```

**pgrep -P** lists PIDs of all childs (not recursively)