# How to kill child processes in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, process, openssl, kill-process

I am trying to do an operation in linux trying to burn cpu using openssl speed

this is my code from netflix simian army

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script for BurnCpu Chaos Monkey

cat << EOF > /tmp/infiniteburn.sh
#!/bin/bash
while true;
   do openssl speed;
done
EOF

# 32 parallel 100% CPU tasks should hit even the biggest EC2 instances
for i in {1..32}
do
  nohup /bin/bash /tmp/infiniteburn.sh &
done
```

so this is Netflix simian army code to do burn cpu, this executes properly but the issue is I cannot kill all 32 processes, I tried everything

```
pkill -f pid/process name
killall -9 pid/process name
etc.,
```

the only successful way I killed the process is through killing it via user

```
pkill -u username
```

How can I kill these process without using username?

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `kill -9 pid`?

Comment: yes I tried that no luck

Comment: Possibly related/maybe a duplicate: [Best way to kill all child processes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/392022). Closely related is [How to kill all subprocesses of shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2618403/) Someone with more Bash experience then me who understands the subtleties will have to decide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

finally, I found a solution to my own question,

```
kill -- -$(ps -o pgid= $PID | grep -o [0-9]*)
```

where PID is the process ID of any of the one processes running, this works fine but I am open to hear any other options available

source: http://fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/237-ways-to-kill-parent-and-child-processes-in-one-command

Answer (score 3):

Killing a process doesn't automatically kill its children. Killing your bash script won't kill the `openssl speed` processes.

You can either cast a wider net with your `kill` call, which is what you're doing with `pkill -u`. Or you could use `trap` in your script and add an error handler.

```
cleanup() {
    # kill children
}

trap cleanup EXIT
```

Comment: You can either cast a wider net with your kill call??? could you please provide more info on this,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solution where I needed to kill a NodeJS server after some amount of time.

To do this, I enabled [Job control](https://ss64.com/bash/set.html), and killed async processes by group id with [jobs](https://ss64.com/bash/jobs.html):

```sh
set -m
./node_modules/.bin/node src/index.js &
sleep 2

kill -- -$(jobs -p)
```