# Auto kill process in Linux

Tags: linux, process

How can I do this task: if I kill a process, that process and other processes will all die ?

Comment: This question is not clear and maybe not related to programming.

Comment: Define "other processes"? Selected ones? All?

Answer (score 2):

Kill the init process.

Answer (score 0):

If you kill the parent process, child processes will remain and become a zombie.

Comment: you've confused zombie and orphan

Answer (score 0):

There are many nice answers about process termination under Linux in general here : [Best way to kill all child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes)

Since I'm not too sure what you mean with that ambiguous question, I'm afraid this is the best answer I can give you.