# Killing a process created with Python's subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, popen

Here is my thought:

First of all, I created a process by using subprocess.Popen

Second, after certain amount of time, I tried to kill it by Popen.kill()

```
import subprocess
import os, signal
import time

proc1 = subprocess.Popen("kvm -hda /path/xp.img", shell = True)
time.sleep(2.0)
print 'proc1 = ', proc1.pid
subprocess.Popen.kill(proc1)
```

However, "proc1" still exists after Popen.kill().
Could any experts tell me how to solve this issue?
I appreciate your considerations.

Thanks to the comments from all experts, I did all you recommended, but result still remains the same.

`proc1.kill() #it sill cannot kill the proc1`

```
os.kill(proc1.pid, signal.SIGKILL) # either cannot kill the proc1
```

Thank you all the same.

And I am still waiting for your precious experience on solving this delicate issue.

Comment: Why do you need the "shell = True"?  Without this it seems to work exactly how you would expect.

Comment: Instead of putting [Solved] in the title, please choose the correct answer clicking on the check symbol.

Comment: proper answer is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Comment: `subprocess.Popen.kill(proc)` is exactly the same as `proc.kill()` FYI.

Comment: it is unlikely that [`kill -9` doesn't work](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/1321). Your issue could be that you need to [kill the whole process tree](http://stackoverflow.com/q/392022/4279).

Answer (score 55):

In your code it should be

```
proc1.kill()
```

Both [`kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) or [`terminate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) are methods of the [`Popen` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects). On macOS and Linux, `kill` sends the signal [`signal.SIGKILL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGKILL) to the process and `terminate` sends [`signal.SIGTERM`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGTERM). On Windows they both call Windows' [`TerminateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess) function.

Comment: Thanks first. However, I tried this one, it still does not work...

Comment: `kill()` and `terminate()` are different
The kill method sends a SIGKILL signal, where the terminate method sends a SEGTERM signal. The difference is that the former it literally terminate the process where the latter it only stops the process.

Answer (score 44):

`process.terminate()` doesn't work when using `shell=True`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/2022481) will help you.

Comment: thank you very much, your answer ended my 3 hours debugging

Comment: works for Windows binaries....

Answer (score 13):

Only use `Popen` kill method

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    task.getExecutable(), 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
    shell=True
)
process.kill()
```

Comment: This does work until I add up "time.sleep(x)" in front of "process.kill()"..

Answer (score 0):

How about using os.kill?  See the docs here: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill

Comment: Thanks, but "os.kill(proc1.pid, signal.SIGTERM)" or "os.kill(proc1.pid, signal.SIGKILL)" are not working..