# Terminate a subprocess if string is in output

Tags: python, if-statement, subprocess, shlex

I'm trying to terminate a subprocess pid if a string is in the output, but it is not working. What is wrong?

```
import subprocess
import shlex


if "PING" in subprocess.check_call(shlex.split("ping -c 10 gogole.com")):
    subprocess.check_call(shlex.split("ping -c 10 gogole.com")).terminate()
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084322/killing-a-process-created-with-pythons-subprocess-popen

Comment: `subprocess.check_call()` doesn't return until the process has exited, so there's nothing to terminate.

Comment: It also doesn't return the process output, it returns a `CompletedProcess` object. If you want the output, use `check_output()`, not `check_call()`.

Comment: If you want to run a subprocess without waiting for it to exit, use `subprocess.Popen()` and then read from the pipe.

Comment: you are right about Popen.

process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("ping -c 10 gogole.com"), stdout=PIPE )
readme = process.stdout.read()
if "PING" in readme:
    print "yes, is there"

Answer (score 0):

Please refere to the documentation for the methods you call.  First of all, [check_call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) executes until the process is finished, then returns the return code from the process.  I'm not sure how you intend to find "PING" from a return code, which is typically an integer.

If it *is* there, look at the body of your `if` statement: you fork a totally new instance of `ping`, wait for it to complete, and then try to terminate the return code.

I recommend that you work through a tutorial on subprocesses.  Learn how to grab a process handle and invoke operations on *that*.  You'll need to get a handle on the output stream, look for "PING" in *that*, and then call `terminate` on the process handle you got at invocation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess, os
run = "ping -c 10 google.com"
log = ""
process = subprocess.Popen(run, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)
    log +=out
    print log
    if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
    if "PING" in log:
        print "terminated!"
        process.kill()
        process.terminate()
        break
```