# How can I get past the Fortran PAUSE message?

Tags: bash

I'm running an old Fortran code as part of a bash script. It completes the execution of its main purpose and then writes this to stdout and hangs:

```
FORTRAN PAUSE  
PAUSE prompt> To continue from background, execute 'kill -15 2658
```

I don't have access to the source code, but from [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vnal/index.html) it looks like it's executing a FORTRAN PAUSE statement and waiting for user input. I expected to be able to do something like this to redirect stdin to it to get it to proceed:

```
my_fortran_code <<EOF
go
EOF
```

but no luck. It still just hangs with the same message.

If I could just automatically terminate it somehow after it gets to the PAUSE and proceed with the rest of the bash script that would be great. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

It's run on a remote machine that I can't log into and manually kill it by the pid. The runtime is important, and I can't just wait X minutes expecting a termination by that time. I'm guessing some kind of wrapper that runs this as a subprocess or thread and reads the text output and kills it may be the way to go...

Comment: Maybe you can use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect).

Answer (score 3):

It actually tells you what needs to be done, you need to run `kill -15 2658`.

Open another bash terminal and run it, and it should continue.

It's mentioned in the docs you linked, at this part:

> If stdin is not a tty I/O device, PAUSE displays a message like this:
>
> ```
> PAUSE: To resume execution, type: kill -15 pid
> ```
>
> where pid is the process ID.
>
> Example: stdin not a tty I/O device:
>
> ```
> demo% a.out < mydatafile
> PAUSE: To resume execution, type: kill -15 20537
> demo%
> ```
>
> For the above example, type the following command line at a shell
> prompt in some other window. The window displaying the message cannot
> accept command input.
>
> ```
> demo% kill -15 20537
> ```

Comment: It's on a randomly assigned compute node that I don't have direct access to after the job is started. Any idea how to do that automatically from within the same bash script?

Comment: Hmmm that's a different problem, I'd suggest to read the output and maybe send it into another bash call. You will need to run this in background, to make it parallel. Or maybe `expect` might be able to help.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping I was making it more complicated than it was, but it seems like maybe I was on the right track haha

Comment: You can run it under `expect` and look for the PAUSE message. It seems it would be better if you could rearrange the code so that it does get access to a TTY on stdin, but maybe that's infeasible.

Comment: Or, as a simple and very crude workaround, run it in the background, get the PID, sleep for a safe amount of time, then send the signal on the assumption that it must have reached the PAUSE by then. `fortrancode & pid=$!; sleep 600; kill -15 "pid"` assumes 10 minutes should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for a simple solution, but alas here I am. I wrote a Python wrapper to kill the process when it detects "FORTRAN PAUSE" in the output stream. It's based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770575/5626104), but upgraded to Python 3 adapted for my purposes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
import sys
import os
import subprocess

print('len(sys.argv):', len(sys.argv))
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print(
        '''This script wraps a command and waits until the output contains "FORTRAN PAUSE" then kills the process.
        
Syntax: 
    skip_fortran_pause.py compiled_fortran_program
'''
    )
    sys.exit(0)

print('Running "{}" until "FORTRAN PAUSE" is detected...'.format(sys.argv[-1]), flush=True)


run = sys.argv[-1]
log = ""
process = subprocess.Popen(run, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1).decode('utf-8')
    if out=='\n':
        # indent the wrapped function
        out = '\n    '
    log += out
    print(out, end='', flush=True)
    if (out == "") and (process.poll() is not None):
        break
    if "FORTRAN PAUSE" in log:
        print('\n"FORTRAN PAUSE" detected. exiting {}... ', flush=True, end="")
        process.kill()
        process.terminate()
        print("done.", flush=True)
        break
```