# How can i kill Discord.py Bot while using SubProcess

Tags: python, discord.py, subprocess, python-asyncio

I have a basic discord.py bot and I want to run it in another script using subprocess.

My Discord Bot's code:

```py
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(f'Message from {message.author}: {message.content}')
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
            await message.channel.send('Hello!')

        if message.content.startswith('!suicide'):
            await message.channel.send('bye...')
            await client.close()

        if message.content.startswith('!img'):
            await message.channel.send(file=discord.File("./caption.gif"))
            
            channel = self.get_channel(channelID)  # channel id should be an int

            if not channel:
                print("There is no channel with this channel id!")
                return

            if message.content.startswith('!img'):
                await message.channel.send(file=discord.File("./caption.gif"))

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('token')
```

And here is subprocess code:

```py
import subprocess

dcBotScript = "./dcBot4SubProcess.py"

print("started")

process = subprocess.Popen(["python", dcBotScript], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I tried `process.terminate()`, `process.kill()`, and somethings with psutil but not worked.

Comment: is here your answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084322/killing-a-process-created-with-pythons-subprocess-popen