# Kill all relevant processes in a PHP script in Linux

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, process

Say I have a PHP script,

```
//main.php -> PID = 1002
<?php 
exec('ProcessOne');
exec('ProcessTwo');
//... many other exec calls
?>
```

The main.php creates many other processes with their own pids which may not be recorded/tracked by the script, but the pid of main.php is known.

My question is: how do I kill all those processes created by main.php(including main.php) by only knowing the pid of main.php which is 1002 in my example?

The script should run in Linux.

Thanks

Comment: How would you kill a process in linux shell? How would you determine child processes? (this question is irrelevant to php)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I described it in such detail is because using exec in php may give processes more relationship than I know: same group id? or something else that I may not know but may be useful to solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pkill -TERM -P 1002
```

`pkill -P PID` gives you all child-proccess, `-TERM` sends the `TERM` Signal to all children.

To kill the children of the children:

```
kill `pstree -p 1002 | sed 's/(/\n(/g' | grep '(' | sed 's/(\(.*\)).*/\1/' | tr "\n" " "`
```

Modified version from [Walking a process tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213973/walking-a-process-tree/5311362#5311362).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but using pkill -TERM -P 1002 only kills direct children of pid 1002. Assuming the ProcessOne has other children processes running as well, what should we do to kill all of those given pid 1002?Thanks