# how to kill process and child processes from python?

Tags: python

for example from bash:

```
kill -9 -PID
```

`os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)` kill only parent process.

Comment: what code did you actually run to solve your problem?

Comment: did you also want to kill the parent process...I assume just the child process right?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you pass a *negative* PID to `kill`, it actually sends the signal to the process *group* by that (absolute) number. You do the equivalent with `os.killpg()` in Python.

Comment: os.killpg() is not available on Windows

Comment: can you provide the actual code so I can kill the child process? Your answer doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: @CharlieParker, use `kill -9 -17351` to kill a group process rather than `kill -9 17351` to kill only the parent process. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/whats-the-best-way-to-send-a-signal-to-all-members-of-a-process-group

Answer (score 57):

If the parent process is not a "process group" but you want to kill it with the children, you can use psutil (https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#processes).  os.killpg cannot identify pid of a non-process-group.

```
import psutil

parent_pid = 30437   # my example
parent = psutil.Process(parent_pid)
for child in parent.children(recursive=True):  # or parent.children() for recursive=False
    child.kill()
parent.kill()
```

Comment: what is a process group and why is that needed to do this?

Comment: Very good answer. I had a use case where `killpg` would kill the process group in which my current process was as well which would terminate the whole program.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution if your **process is not a process group** and you **don't want to use psutil**, is to run this shell command:

```
pkill -TERM -P 12345
```

For instance with

```
os.system('pkill -TERM -P {pid}'.format(pid=12345))
```

Answer (score 2):

None of answers can helped me, so I made some research and wrote my answer:
you can easily do it using `os` module, but it is platform sensitive. This mean that some commands are availiable only on Unix, some - on any platform.
So my project starts one Process, and several Child processes in the different places and times. Some of Child starts Grand-Child Processes :)
So I found this solution:

```
import os
import signal
import platform
# get the current PID for safe terminate server if needed:
PID = os.getpid()
if platform.system() != 'Windows':
    PGID = os.getpgid(PID)
if platform.system() != 'Windows':
    os.killpg(PGID, signal.SIGKILL)
else:
    os.kill(PID, signal.SIGTERM)
```

I use `SIGKILL` on Linux, to kill process immediatly, and `SIGTERM` on Windows, because there is no `SIGKILL` on it.
Also I used `killpg()` to kill the whole group of processes on Linux.

P.S. Check on Linux, but still doesn't check on Windows, so maybe we need one more additional command for Windows (for example CTRL_C_EVENT or [use another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27034438/4960953).)

Comment: Use `!= 'Windows"` instead of `is not "Windows"`. Strings are not guaranteed to be interned in Python.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you asked for, but if you wish to kill other processes of your application and they were all created using multiprocessing package you can do something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep

...

def on_shutdown():
    for child in multiprocessing.active_children():
        print('Terminating', child)
        child.terminate()
        sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use signal parameter 9 to kill the process tree.

```
root@localhost:~$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.kill(pid, 9)
```

if you should use `signal.SIGKILL constant`, you should use `os.killpg(pgid, signal.SIGKILL)` to kill the process tree.

Comment: os.kill(pid,9) is worked for me, i use python 2.7 on centos 5.6

Comment: Yes, `os.kill(pid, 9)` works when `signal.SIGKILL` happens to be `9`, which is on most platforms. Nevertheless, `signal.SIGKILL` is the right constant to use, and using `9` instead of `signal.SIGKILL` is not an improvement nor does it in any way solve the OP's problem.

Comment: you are right, if you have to use signal.SIGKILL constant, you should use os.killpg(pgid, signal.SIGKILL) to kill a group process.

Answer (score -1):

```
def kill_children_processes(pid):
    # TODO: Find a way to not have to use a kill -9.
    processes = os.popen("ps -ej | grep -i 'python' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{ print $2,$3 }'").read()
    processes = [p.split(" ") for p in processes.split("\n")[:-1]]
    processes = "\n".join([child for child, parent in processes if parent == str(pid) and child != str(pid)])
    if processes:
        logger.debug(f"Killing ghost processes {processes}")
        os.system(f"kill -9 {processes}")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).