# Python killing process using psutil

Tags: python, linux, psutil

I'm trying to use python `psutil` library to create and kill process. My script starts an process, and then tries to kill started subprocess. I run same code under Windows and Linux. Under Windows everything works well. Under Linux `psutils` starts subprocess correctly(so started app is script's child and it executed with same privileges as the script, but when I try to kill the process `psutil` detaches from the process but not kills. Here is starting app code:

```
self.__proc = psutil.Popen(cmd, cwd=working_directory, env=env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

After this I try to kill started child process:

```
self.__proc.kill()
        self.__proc = None
```

I got same behavior using this:

```
while psutil.pid_exists(pid):
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    if p is not None:
        p.kill()
```

Can anyone explain why I can't kill process started by me? What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using **Python 2.7**.

Comment: Probably your child app start subprocesses? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549669/how-to-kill-process-and-child-processes-from-python

Comment: Try passing `signal.SIGKILL` arguement  in `p.kill()`. Not tried though.