# providing input with subprocess module

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to **lock screen in the ubuntu server using "gnome-screensaver-command"** and then unlock it by pressing enter key. This is working fine when I am doing it manually and hence thought of automating the same with Python Subprocess module.

The **problem I am facing is it is locking the screen and after the timer expiry the enter key**("echo -ne \n", got to know this can be used to send enter through CLI) **is not happening**.

Below is the code snippet.

```
import subprocess
import time


cmd = subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command", "-l"])
time.sleep(10)
subprocess.call(["echo", "-ne", "\n"])
```

Tried another way of doing it:

```
#******THIS METHOD IS NOT LOCKING THE SCREEN AT ALL*******

cmd = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command", "-l"], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
time.sleep(10)
cmd.communicate(input="\n")
```

What should be done to work it as per my requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the screensaver reads the keyboard but not through the process standard input.

Something that (maybe) would work would be to send a keyboard event to the desktop. There are programs (like `caffeine` on Windows) which do that to prevent the screensaver from activating, but let me propose a portable alternative which doesn't involve keyboard events:

- run the process
- wait 10 seconds
- kill the screensaver process

like this:

```
import subprocess
import time


cmd = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command", "-l"])
time.sleep(10)
cmd.terminate()
```

Comment: the process is not getting killed with terminate, as you have suggested.

Comment: arg... annoying. Does the script end or stays stuck?

Comment: try to replace `cmd.terminate()` by `os.kill(cmd.pid)`. But I have little hope.

Comment: true: `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGKILL)` then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549669/how-to-kill-process-and-child-processes-from-python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146783/discussion-between-here-2-learn-and-jean-francois-fabre).