# Python subprocess kill with timeout

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running some shell scripts with the subprocess module in python. If the shell scripts is running to long, I like to kill the subprocess. I thought it will be enough if I am passing the `timeout=30` to my `run(..)` statement.

Here is the code:

```
try:
    result=run(['utilities/shell_scripts/{0} {1} {2}'.format(
                        self.language_conf[key][1], self.proc_dir, config.main_file)],
                shell=True,
                check=True,
                stdout=PIPE,
                stderr=PIPE, 
                universal_newlines=True, 
                timeout=30,
                bufsize=100)
except TimeoutExpired as timeout:
```

I have tested this call with some shell scripts that runs 120s. I expected the subprocess to be killed after 30s, but in fact the process is finishing the 120s script and than raises the Timeout Exception. Now the Question how can I kill the subprocess by timeout?

Comment: have you tried legacy methods with `Popen` ?

Comment: What do you have in your `except` block?  From the doc:  "*The child process is not killed if the timeout expires, so in order to cleanup properly a well-behaved application should kill the child process and finish communication*"

Comment: I have read the official document, it sends `SIGKILL` to kill the subprocess. Maybe your script cannot be killed by `SIGKILL`? Try it in raw terminal.

Comment: @cdarke That is the behavior of `Popen` but not `run`. `run` will kill the child process.

Comment: @Sraw:  sorry, you are right.  I would still like to know what is in the `except` block though.

Comment: @Sraw `SIGKILL` never fails, at least in *nix.

Comment: @liliscent I'm not sure about it as wikipedia tells me there are some exceptions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals. See SIGKILL part.

Comment: @cdarke: from the [docs for `subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html): "The timeout argument is passed to Popen.communicate(). If the timeout expires, the child process will be killed and waited for. The TimeoutExpired exception will be re-raised after the child process has terminated."

Comment: @cdarke In the expect block is only a logging statement, that's it.

Comment: For more background information.  I am starting a shell script to execute some programs, which are send by students. This is part of some sort of automated testing of the uploads. Sometimes the students have some permanent loops `while True: ...`. These programs are blocking the testing chain, so I like to kill them after a timeout. The programs can be written in Python, C, matlab etc. That's why I am using shell scripts to start (and compile) them.

Comment: Unless you are using shell built-in commands or shell meta-characters then you don't need a shell.  Shell scripts can be run as any other program.

Comment: I need shell comments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation explicitly states that the process should be killed:

from the [docs for `subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> "The timeout argument is passed to Popen.communicate(). If the timeout expires, the child process will be killed and waited for. The TimeoutExpired exception will be re-raised after the child process has terminated."

But in your case you're using `shell=True`, and I've seen issues like that before, because the blocking process is a child of the shell process.

I don't think you need `shell=True` if you decompose your arguments properly and your scripts have the proper shebang. You could try this:

```
result=run(
  [os.path.join('utilities/shell_scripts',self.language_conf[key][1]), self.proc_dir, config.main_file],  # don't compose argument line yourself
            shell=False,  # no shell wrapper
            check=True,
            stdout=PIPE,
            stderr=PIPE, 
            universal_newlines=True, 
            timeout=30,
            bufsize=100)
```

note that I can reproduce this issue very easily on Windows (using `Popen`, but it's the same thing):

```
import subprocess,time

p=subprocess.Popen("notepad",shell=True)
time.sleep(1)
p.kill()
```

=> notepad stays open, probably because it manages to detach from the parent shell process.

```
import subprocess,time

p=subprocess.Popen("notepad",shell=False)
time.sleep(1)
p.kill()
```

=> notepad closes after 1 second

Funnily enough, if you remove `time.sleep()`, `kill()` works even with `shell=True` probably because it successfully kills the shell which is launching `notepad`.

I'm not saying you have exactly the same issue, I'm just demonstrating that `shell=True` is evil for many reasons, and not being able to kill/timeout the process is one more reason.

However, *if* you need `shell=True` for a reason, you can use `psutil` to kill all the children in the end. In that case, it's better to use `Popen` so you get the process id directly:

```
import subprocess,time,psutil

parent=subprocess.Popen("notepad",shell=True)
for _ in range(30): # 30 seconds
    if parent.poll() is not None:  # process just ended
      break
    time.sleep(1)
else:
   # the for loop ended without break: timeout
   parent = psutil.Process(parent.pid)
   for child in parent.children(recursive=True):  # or parent.children() for recursive=False
       child.kill()
   parent.kill()
```

(source: [how to kill process and child processes from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549669/how-to-kill-process-and-child-processes-from-python))

that example kills the notepad instance as well.

Comment: In `run`'s source code, it also use `kill()` to terminate child process. So in this case, I don't think this will work. But who knows...

Comment: @Sraw: I think it's the bloody shell=True which causes the issue.

Comment: I'm... still not sure about it as I have never seen this behavior. Since you said you have seen it, could you do us a favor by providing an example which will cause this situation?

Comment: @Sraw actually I _can_. I'm using windows, but I'm sure it can be reproduced on Linux as well.

Comment: Because of some reasons, I need to execute the commands in the shell, so `shell=true` is necessary.  When I am not using the statement I get an `FileNotFoundError`. Or is this error caused by an other false configuration?

Comment: @Max: see my edit, it's possible with `Popen` and psutil package which kills all the children manually.

Comment: I have tested it with `subprocess.run`. And it doesn't work as expected. Surely after killing child process, `notepad` is still opening. But `subprocess.run` is also returned and raises a `TimeoutExpired` exception. So part of you have said is true, it won't fully kill `notepad`. But part is wrong, it won't block `subprocess.run` as `subprocess.run` is blocked by `shell` process but not all of its children. BTW, I tested it on Windows.

Comment: the problem with `subprocess.run` is that you cannot get the process id / when exception is called the master process is already killed. That's why I'm recommending `Popen` instead

Comment: The psutil suggestion isn't reliable on Windows. A process only has the PID of its parent, which may have already exited. The way to do this reliably in Windows 8+ is with a Job object that disallows silent breakaway (or disallows breakaway entirely, but that may cause failures if a subprocess insists on breaking a child out of the job). Create the process suspended (avoid race conditions), assign it to the job, and then resume it. Windows 7 doesn't support nested jobs, so if Python is in a job already, you can try to break the child out, but it may be disallowed.

Comment: I encountered the same issue as OP but with Shell=False, using python 3.6.9 on Ubuntu 18 (but NOT with Python 3.8 on Windows). Turns out this is/was a bug https://bugs.python.org/issue37424 fixed in Python 3.7+ - process should now in fact be killed upon timeout and not continue. Not sure yet how to workaround the bug on Linux machines where I can't upgrade python.

Comment: Update: The bug issue37424 above is "fixed" in Python 3.7.5 to be precise. Also, I upgraded via `sudo apt install python3.8` on Ubuntu 18 and now timeout is "honored" (thread is not blocked). Yet the actual process I called is not killed and continues (which may be a problem with my process not honoring termination call, dunno).