# How can i kill process that i have started with python

Tags: python

So I made a program that opens tor browser and I need to kill that browser after some time how can I do that

I have tried to kill it with os.system and Linux commands

And this is command with whic I start the browser

```
    subprocess.call(['./start-tor-browser.desktop'])
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763362/python-subprocess-kill-with-timeout

Comment: I have tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), it says:

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the `returncode` attribute.

`subprocess.call` waits for the command to finish, i.e until Tor is closed in your case. Instead, you can use the lower-level `Popen` API [directly](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) which lets you control the process after it's been spawned.

In that case, your code would end up looking something like this:

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(['./start-tor-browser.desktop'])
# ...
# do other stuff here
p.kill()
```

Answer (score -1):

On linux you can do

```sh
ps -fea | grep -i 'tor'
OR
pgrep applicationName
```

to find the process/pid. And to kill the tor process

```sh
kill <pid>
```

The command `ps -fea | grep <process-name>` will enumerate all processes running with name