# Opposite of os.system(), closing a python program

Tags: python

Is there a command to close a python program?
if I run with os.system("name.py"), how can I stop it from running?

```
os.system("name.py")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549669/how-to-kill-process-and-child-processes-from-python

Comment: but where do I write the name?

Comment: The easy answer is: don't run it with `os.system`. The docs for [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) tell you that pretty clearly: "The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section in the subprocess documentation for some helpful recipes." If you use `subprocess`, you can spawn a child and then kill it later.

Comment: This is at least the third question you've posted in the past few weeks where the answer is "If you just use `subprocess` instead of `os.system` that process wouldn't even come up in the first place." Why are you so resistant to doing things the easy way? Are you even looking at the answers you get for these questions? (You haven't accepted any of them.)

Comment: Sorry, I am stuck at somewhere and I can't change the whole code just to use subprocess, I didn't accept because there was this red message popping each time I tried to accept. Why are you angry? sorry...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subprocesses instead.

```
import subprocess

# Start
proc = subprocess.Popen(["name.py"])

# Stop
proc.terminate()
```

Comment: and how do I move sys.argvs to name.py?

Comment: I mean variables.. , after the name with a space?

Comment: Just at them after the name with a space. Ex: "name.py arg1 arg2 arg3"

Comment: i can only in 1 minutes.

Comment: hey, how do I call "proc" ? its gray for me so it means I dont use it

Comment: You don't HAVE to call proc, you can just assign it and leave it

Comment: hi,moving parameters doesnt work for me, it says it doesnt find the file, maybe because I concatenated the name with the variables?

Comment: Ah my bad, do ["name.py", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3"] instead

Comment: it says WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application