# subprocess fail to kill make command

Tags: python, makefile, subprocess

If I run `'make'` command in `subprocess.Popen` it doesn't terminate after timeout

```
    with subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as process:
    try:
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        process.kill()
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

I tried will

```
subprocess.check_output and subprocess.run
```

and they also don't work.

If a run each command from Makefile independently using the method above, it works fine.

Comment: why are you passing some input if you don't redirect input?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the input doesn't matter in my case. And yes, it can be removed. The issue is that the 'make' command doesn't terminate. Inside Makefile there is a program launch with an infinity loop and if I run it this way instead of 'make' it was killed successfully

Answer (score 0):

When using `subprocess` I often try to do pursue the easiest path to get the desired result. Having said that, I would recommend just adding a timeout to your script being called and eliminate any need to try and kill it.

For example:

```
timeout_length = 30 # seconds
command = "make"
subprocess.Popen(['timeout', timeout_length, command], 
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine on Linux, but there is no timeout on MacOS. There is an alternative, but it makes the program platform dependant and/or require extra tools to install

Comment: `subprocess.run` and friends hae a `timeout` keyword argument; use that intead of bare `Popen` maybe. The `Popen` documentation specifically recommends that you should avoid it and prefer the higher-level `subprocess` functions whenever you can.

Answer (score 0):

one classical issue is that

```
process.kill()
```

doesn't kill child processes. Maybe in your case, a child process is running and isn't stopped, specially if the main makefile calls other makefiles.

In that case, apply the recipe found in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27034438/6451573%20adapted%20to%20the%20current%20situation) to [how to kill process and child processes from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549669/how-to-kill-process-and-child-processes-from-python)

```
import psutil

with subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as process:
try:
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    # create a parent psutil process object
    parent = psutil.Process(process.pid)
    # list all child processes and kill them
    for child in parent.children(recursive=True):  # or parent.children() for recursive=False
       child.kill()
    # kill parent process as done earlier
    process.kill()
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```