# Child process not getting killed with Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used `child_process.exec` / `child_process.spawn` to fork a new process and then kill it using `child.kill` / `process.kill`. It works fine with simple binary executables, such as `cat` / `ls`, and the child process just get killed.

However, when get to **the scripts (say P1)** that **forks another child process (say P2)**, only the script interpreter P1 get killed, not the child process P2.

**QUESTION**: is there any way that getting such child process P2 killed with Node.JS?

Code works fine with `run_and_kill('ls -Al /usr/lib')`, but not OK with `run_and_kill('firefox')`:

```
function run_and_kill(cmd) {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec,
        ls = exec(cmd);
    console.log('Child process started: %d', ls.pid);
    ls.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
        console.log('exit with code %s and signal %s', code, signal);
    });
    ls.kill();
}
```

Comment: you can try to kill them manually (probably P2 ignores SIGHUP) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes

Comment: @AndreySidorov How to kill manually w/o knowing its PID?

Comment: you know it - `ls.pid` ( https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L250 )

Comment: @AndreySidorov I mean PID of P2 since kill P1 does not make P2 exits.

Comment: you can try to pass group id when spawn p2 and use it to kill

Comment: @AndreySidorov P1 is a read-only script not necessarily written with Node.JS. And how to get the group PID and kill P1/P2 both with Node.JS?

Comment: can you handle GIGHUP in your p2 node.js script?

Comment: It depends on what P2 is. I'm not as familiar with Firefox, but with Chrome, as soon as you start it, the PID changes due to it's process per tab model and you are unable to kill it using the original reference to the process. This may be what is happening here.

Answer (score 4):

The safest way I've found to achieve this is creating a spawn process to kill the signal, using the child.pid as argument. Example with fork :

```
var process;
process = require('child_process');

var fork, child;
fork = process.fork;
child = fork('./index');

var spawn;
spawn = process.spawn;
spawn('kill', [child.pid]);
console.log('sending SIGTERM to child process (socket server)');
```

I typically use this in specs, mostly in beforeAll/afterAll blocks to start/kill servers (in the example './index.js').

Comment: this works, as long as *those* child processes exit too :) which they should

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was the shell being used for the process. By default it's `/bin/sh`, and when this was being used it wasn't handling the kill signals.

To fix this you can use `/bin/bash` instead:

```js
exec('your command', {
    shell: '/bin/bash',
});
```

Comment: Any idea what the equivalent solution would be on a Windows system?

Answer (score 1):

I think your **P2** is neither a fork or a child of **P1** but rather a parallel process spawned by it. In the case of Firefox ( at least in Linux ) the firefox app is launched by a wrapper shell script. If it's always going to be firefox, better run the binary straight from it's install folder