# Bash pipe and SIGTERM

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, supervisord

I have a Bash script "script" which roughly looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3
```

When I do a `kill script` (or more precisely when I do a 'stop script' in `supervisord`), not all cmd* are killed.  How can I make sure they are terminated along with the script that spawned them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Supervisord has **stopasgroup** and **killasgroup** options (false by default) which determine whether to propagate SIGTERM/SIGKILL signals to child processes.

```
[program:script]
command=script
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

(These config variables are both documented at http://supervisord.org/configuration.html.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about how using `supervisord`, but with `pkill` you can use the `-P` option to kill from a parent process down to all the children. Here's the process trees (starting from my running ssh daemon).

```
$ pstree -a -p 1792
sshd,1792
  ├─sshd,27150
  │   └─sshd,27153
  │       └─zsh,27154
  │           └─test.sh,27325 ./test.sh
  │               └─cat,27326
  └─sshd,27182
      └─sshd,27184
          └─zsh,27185
              └─pstree,27357 -a -p 1792
```

In one session I have a script `test.sh` with pid 27325, and in the other I'm running the command `pstree -a -p 1792` (because `sshd` had pid 1792)

And after I run `pkill -TERM -P 27325`:

```
$ pstree -a -p 1792   
sshd,1792
  ├─sshd,27150
  │   └─sshd,27153
  │       └─zsh,27154
  └─sshd,27182
      └─sshd,27184
           └─zsh,27185
              └─pstree,27387 -a -p 1792
```

This answer was essentially rephrased from the this other answer on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/392155/263969

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to trap SIGTERM and kill all children in the trap-code.

The only thing is that the shell runs trap-code for a received signal only after the currently running command has completed -- so in your case, this alone wouldn't help.

However, traps will be run in an "async" kind of way if the shell is in "wait".

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
trap 'kill 0' TERM
( cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3 ) & wait
```

The `kill 0` sends SIGTERM to all processes in the current process group.

NOTE: I'm talking about Bash here.