# Bash : run a command and wait if necessary (contrary of timeout)

Tags: bash, timeout

I have a 10 second interval. I want to run a command in a shell, then wait to complete the 10 sec interval. If the commands takes more than 10 seconds, its OK.

I am looking for an equivalent to "foo" function below :

```
>> foo 10 python myscript.py
```

- If myscript.py takes 2 seconds, the shell should wait 8 seconds afterwhile.
- If myscript.py takes 5 seconds, the shell should wait 5 seconds afterwhile.
- If myscript.py takes 12 seconds, the shell should not wait. It should not timeout myscript.py either !

Does this "foo" function exist ?

Comment: I wrote a answer for a similar problem over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41108021/771740

Comment: I answer a similar question over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41108021/771740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run both `sleep 10` and your script in the background, then wait for both to complete.

```
python myscript.py &
sleep 10 &
wait
```

You can define a shell function to wrap *simple* commands (a command name and its arguments; no pipes, redirections, `&&` and `||`, etc.)

```
foo () {
    t=$1
    shift
    "$@" &
    sleep "$t" &
    wait
}

foo 10 python myscript.py
```