# How to kill Django runserver sub processes from a bash script?

Tags: python, django, bash, shell

I'm working on a Django website where I have various compilation programs that need to run (Compass/Sass, coffeescript, hamlpy), so I made this shell script for convenience:

```
#!/bin/bash
SITE=/home/dev/sites/rmx

echo "RMX using siteroot=$SITE"
$SITE/rmx/manage.py runserver &
PIDS[0]=$!
compass watch $SITE/media/compass/ &
PIDS[1]=$!
coffee -o $SITE/media/js -cw $SITE/media/coffee &
PIDS[2]=$!
hamlpy-watcher $SITE/templates/hamlpy $SITE/templates/templates &
PIDS[3]=$!

trap "echo PIDS: ${PIDS[*]} && kill ${PIDS[*]}" SIGINT

wait
```

Everything except for the Django server shuts down nicely on a `ctrl+c` because the PID of the server process isn't the PID of the `python manage.py runserver` command. Which means everytime I stop the script, I have to find the running process PID and shut it down.

Here's an example:

```
$> ./compile.sh
   RMX using siteroot....
   ...
   [ctrl+c]
   PIDS: 29725 29726 29728 29729
$> ps -A | grep python
   29732 pts/2    00:00:00 python
```

The first PID, `29725`, is the initial `python manage.py runserver` call, but `29732` is the actual dev server process.

**edit** Looks like this is due to [Django's auto-reload feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---noreload) which can be disabled with the `--noreload` flag. Since I'd like to keep the auto reload feature, the question now becomes how to kill the child processes from the bash script. I would think killing the initial python runserver command would do it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes), I've changed my script to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SITE=/home/dev/sites/rmx

echo "RMX using siteroot=$SITE"
$SITE/rmx/manage.py runserver &
compass watch $SITE/media/compass/ &
coffee -o $SITE/media/js -cw $SITE/media/coffee &
hamlpy-watcher $SITE/templates/hamlpy $SITE/templates/templates &

trap "kill -TERM -$$" SIGINT

wait
```

PIDs preceded with the dash operate on the *PID group* with the `kill` command, and the `$$` references the PID of the bash script itself.

Thanks for the help, me!
No problem, self, and hey -- you're awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute this to kill or process and servers, you set PORT number:

```
$ netstat -tulpn | grep PORT | awk '{print $7}' | cut -d/ -f 1 | xargs kill
```

OR

```
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:PORT
$ sudo lsof -i tcp:PORT|awk '{print $2}'|cut -d/ -f 1|xargs kill
```

Comment: I think you need to pipe the output to kill like so sudo lsof -i tcp:PORT|awk '{print $2}'|cut -d/ -f 1|xargs | kill