# Get child process id

Tags: java, shell, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to kill all child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes)

I am running a script, which runs a java program in the background using the eval command.

```
eval <java java_program & >
```

While running the above command, I found that it creates a new child process. Now when I want to stop the process, in the script I tried with the command '$!', which always gives me only parent process id. So `kill -9 $!` kills the parent process and leaves the child process still running in background.

Is there a way to find all the child processes associated with a process id and kill all the processes? Or what's the efficient way of killing all the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use pstree using the parent pid

and for killing it may worth a visit for this:

[Best way to kill all child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes)