# How to kill a shell script and processes it created?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I run a shell script inside php (using shell_exec). I want to kill it and all processes it created when it is in operation. I know the shell script pid. Do you have any suggestion?
I am using ubuntu, php as apache module.

Thank you.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
sleep 20
```

When I kill my script (shell_exec("sudo kill -9 $pid")), the sleep process is not killed which is not desired.

Comment: In general killing the shell would kill also its child processes. Otherwise, learn about process groups.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
pkill -TERM -P pid
```

will kill the child processes

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481337/1032255)

Comment: it kills the process pid and its children, but not grandchildren or below.

Comment: [anubhava's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17985574/1032255) below can kill all of them, or you can see other answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/392022/1032255), such as [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3211182/1032255), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15139734/1032255)

Answer (score 1):

Use this kill command instead:

```
kill -- -$pid
```

to kill the running script and all its spawned children.

Comment: i do. "sudo kill -- -3768", i got "Kill: No such process".

Comment: You can try it from command line first. I have tried with your script and it worked.