# Cannot rename ifplugd in /usr/sbin folder

Tags: linux

how to uninstall ifplugd?

i try rename ifplugd ifplugd_old but it says Barewood "ifplugd not allowed while "strict subs in use.

looks like it's in use. How to bring it down and rename it or even delete it?

Answer (score 1):

How to remove `ifplugd` depends on which kind of [package management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system) (or Linux distribution) you are using:

1. YUM (Fedora, RHEL, CentOS)

   ```
   yum erase ifplugd
   ```
2. APT (Debian, Ubuntu)

   ```
   apt-get remove ifplugd
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -aux|grep ifplugd
```

read the process id of ifplugd , and then

```
kill -9 process_id
```

Now, you should be able to uninstall it.

Comment: I cannot. After I kill the last process using ifplugd, another one auto spawned with ifplugd.

Comment: what is the state of the process when you issue - ps -aux|grep ifplugd

Comment: Check if this helps:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes