# Kill bash and child process

Tags: c, linux, bash, signals

My C program executes commands in a bash shell.  To do this, I `fork` and in the child process I run:

```
char* command = "..."; /* provided by user */
execlp("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", command, NULL);
```

If this is a long running command, I would like to have the option of killing it.  For example, say I'm doing:

```
execlp("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "find / test", NULL);
```

After this, I know the PID of the child that is executing bash, but bash is forking a separate process to execute find.

```
$ ps aux | grep find
zmb       7802  0.0  0.1   5252  1104 pts/1    S+   11:17   0:00 bash -c find / test
zmb       7803  0.0  0.0   4656   728 pts/1    S+   11:17   0:00 find / test
```

I can kill the bash process (7802), but the find process (7803) still continues to execute.  How can I ensure that the bash process propagates signals to it's children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will send a SIGTERM to the Process Group ID passed in parameter and to all children.

```
kill -- -$(ps -o pgid= $PID | grep -o [0-9]*)
```

Also, more answers on this post : [Best way to kill all child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes)

Comment: It sends a TERM signal to the process `$PID_OF_TEST` and all children

Comment: In this case `--` tells the next `-` to be treated as a negative sign and not a flag.  I had tried this but mistakenly used `kill -- $PID` (was missing the final `-`).

Comment: This isn't quite working for me.  `kill` is returning `ESRCH` (no such process).

Comment: I had to `setsid()` to create a new session in the child before `exec`ing bash.  Everything works as expected now.

Answer (score 3):

from [`man 2 kill`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/kill):

If pid is less than -1, then sig is sent to every process in the process group whose ID is -pid.

That is you may kill all children, direct or indirect which weren't created its own process group.