# How to use trap reliably using Bash running foreground child processes

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script that runs a long running process in the foreground. When it receives a SIGQUIT signal, it should perform various cleanup operations such as killing itself and all of its child processes (via kill of process group etc.). A minimal script, that should catch the signal, is shown below (called `test_trap.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "TRAP CAUGHT"; exit 1' QUIT  # other required signals are omitted for brevity

echo starting sleep
sleep 11666
echo ending sleep

echo done
```

I would like to send the SIGHUP signal to the process of the `test_trap.sh` script.  However, sending a SIGHUP to the `test_trap.sh` does not trigger the trap expression, but only when I send the signal to the child `sleep 11666` process does the trap fire. Below is a bash session demonstrating this:

```
bash-4.1$ test_trap.sh &
[1] 19633
bash-4.1$ starting sleep

bash-4.1$ kill -s SIGQUIT 19633
bash-4.1$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 test_trap.sh &
bash-4.1$ ps -ef --forest --cols=10000 | grep '11666\|test_trap.sh' | grep -v grep
theuser   19633 12227  0 07:40 pts/4    00:00:00              \_ /bin/bash ./test_trap.sh
theuser   19634 19633  0 07:40 pts/4    00:00:00              |   \_ sleep 11666
bash-4.1$ kill -s SIGQUIT 19634
bash-4.1$ Quit (core dumped)
TRAP CAUGHT

[1]+  Exit 1                  test_trap.sh
bash-4.1$ ps -ef --forest --cols=10000 | grep '11666\|test_trap.sh' | grep -v grep
bash-4.1$
```

Note that the "sleep 11666" is just a representative process. That process can actually be an interactive subshell (e.g., `bash -i`).

Why doesn't the parent `test_trap.sh` process catch the SIGHUP signal? Why would the trap fire only when the process for `sleep 11666` was signaled?

I do not want to use uncatchable SIGKILL as I do need to do an assortment of cleanup operations in the trap expression.

This script is intended run on any fairly recent version of any Linux distribution containing Bash (e.g., not Cygwin).

References:

1. [killing Parent process along with child process using SIGKILL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869242/killing-parent-process-along-with-child-process-using-sigkill)
2. [Kill bash and child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032296/kill-bash-and-child-process)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`bash` must wait for `sleep` to complete before it can execute the handler. A good workaround is to run `sleep` in the background, then immediately wait for it. While `sleep` is uninterruptible, `wait` is not.

```
trap 'kill $sleep_pid; echo "TRAP CAUGHT"; exit 1' QUIT

echo starting sleep
sleep 11666 &
sleep_pid=$!
wait
echo ending sleep

echo done
```

The recording of `sleep_pid` and using it to kill `sleep` from the handler are optional.

Comment: I have to mark this as the answer since you asked my question and it was quite helpful. However, I said "That process can actually be an interactive subshell (e.g., bash -i). " and I should have added "I don't want to put the representative process in the background because it could be an interactive shell".

Comment: Keep in mind that the user of the interactive subshell could set their own traps anyway to avoid the shell being interrupted by the caller.

Comment: @bgoodr did you ever find a solution that does not require putting the process in the background?

Comment: @trex005 No, unfortunately I did not.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, bash is receiving the signal, but it is in an *uninterruptible state* waiting for the `sleep` command to end. When it ends, bash will react to the signal and execute the trap.

You can replace the long `sleep` command with a loop of short `sleep` commands:

```
while true
do
    sleep 1
done
```

With that, if you send the signal to the bash process, it will react as soon as the currently executing `sleep` command ends, that is, at most 1 second after it was sent.

Comment: Thanks but see my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240221/how-to-use-trap-reliably-using-bash-running-foreground-child-processes#comment54286155_33241062 as given to @chepner's answer. If sleeping was all I wanted to do, then your answer would suffice, but that is just a representative process that I would ideally like to allow to be running in the foreground since it might end up being a interactive `bash -i` process.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the signal `SIGINT` (the same which is sent by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) instead of `SIGKILL`. Other signals only work when the bash can process I/O or some other condition.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem myself and after a few dozen test I've settled on a solution: running it in the background and "hot-wiring" stdin and stdout to it as if it was in the foreground

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap "echo caught" SIGTERM

the_process <&0 >&1 & # &0 is stdin, &1 stdout
wait
```

No idea if that's considered clean or good practice. Nonetheless it did what i needed it to.