# When using child_process how do I keep track of any extra processes a spawn has created

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm using

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res) {
    pool.query("SELECT MAX(server_port) FROM servers", function(err, rows) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        var serverPort = parseInt(rows[0]['MAX(server_port)']) + 1;
        var decoder = new StringDecoder('utf8')
        var child = spawn('/home/steam/steamcmd/csgo/srcds_run',
        ['-game csgo' ,'-console' ,'+game_type 0' ,'+game_mode ' + req.body.serverType, '+map ' + req.body.serverMap,
        '-tickrate ' + req.body.tickRate, '+maxplayers ' + req.body.maxPlayers,
        '+hostname ' + req.body.serverName, '+port ' + serverPort, '+password '],
        {
            detached: true
        });
        child.stderr.on('data', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
        child.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
        });

        console.log(child.pid);
        var inserts = {
            server_name: req.body.serverName || 'CSGO Quick Server',
            server_players: req.body.maxPlayers,
            server_owned_by: req.session.username,
            serverPID: child.pid,
            server_port: serverPort,
            server_tickrate: req.body.tickRate,
            server_map: req.body.serverMap,
            server_type: req.body.serverType
        };
        pool.query("INSERT INTO `servers` SET ?", inserts, function(err, insert) {
           if (err) return console.log(err);
           res.json({'success': true});
        });
    });
});
```

to create a spawn for CS:GO (video game) to run a server from the front-end, and that is working great, the server goes up and runs. But I have to run the program `./srcds_run` which sets some variables and then runs `./srcds_linux` so I keep track of the PID of `./srcds_run` but when I go to kill it, the `./srcds_linux` still runs and I'm not sure how to get the PID of it.

Trying to `killall` won't work because there might be another `./srcds_linux` running that I do not want to kill.

Basically what I am asking is, how do I kill the process that was created by `./srcds_run`.

This is how I'm destroying it:

```
router.get('/destroy', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.hasOwnProperty('username')) {
        pool.query("SELECT * FROM servers WHERE server_owned_by = ?", [req.session.username], function(err, rows) {
           if (err) return res.redirect('/');
           if (rows.length >= 1) {
               console.log('here');
                exec('kill ' + rows[0].serverPID, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
                   if (err) return console.log(err);
                   if (stderr) return console.log(stderr);
                   console.log(stdout);
                   pool.query("DELETE FROM servers WHERE serverPID = ?", [rows[0].serverPID], function(err) {
                      if (err) console.log(err);
                      res.redirect('/servers');
                   });
                });
           }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

And this is what I end up with

```
root@PanicWoW:~# ps aux | grep csgo
root     16995  0.0  0.0   4440   704 ?        Ss   06:45   0:00 /bin/sh /home/steam/steamcmd/csgo/srcds_run -game csgo -console +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +map de_dust2 -tickrate 64 +maxplayers 10 +hostname  +port 27016 +password 
root     17022  6.3  6.4 262072 132960 ?       Sl   06:45   0:05 ./srcds_linux -game csgo -console +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +map de_dust2 -tickrate 64 +maxplayers 10 +hostname +port 27016 +password
```

So when I `kill 16995`, the other process continues to run instead of dying with it, even though `16995` created it.

Sorry if this is confusing I'm not sure how to word this as it is fairly new area for me (not the JS, but dealing with child_processes and linux) thanks a lot. If I can clarify anything please ask.

Comment: I think this is a much more linux aligned question instead of being related to node.js, perhaps taking a look at the following SO question might she some light to answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the Process group ID is the same as the first process, so by using `KILL -TERM -####` I can kill the entire tree.