# python subprocess stuck system command

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, kill-process

I'm not sure if python subprocess stuck the system. I run the GenomeAnalysisTK-3.4-46 as a subprocess through the python os.system(). But the `java GenomeAnalysisTK.jar` command status turned to "D" which can't be killed. [when i run `top -u username` i get this, but if i click 'c', it stuck the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SmKZ.png)

Beside, if i run the command `ps aux`,the command is blocked and the terminal is stuck. Even though the system runs well, it's really annoying monitoring your commands when the terminal stuck all the time.

I tried to figure out how it stuck system command,[i prompted `strace ps aux`,i got this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Rc3P.png), the process can't be killed, and more and more command blocked when met the process. What i can do is reboot server manually by pressing power off, because restart command didn't work.

My python version is 2.7.6, and ubuntu release is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I want to know how it happened and how to fix it up not by pressing power off.

Comment: *«java GenomeAnalysisTK.jar command status turned to "D" which can't be killed.»* -- ["kill -9 (SIGKILL) always works"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5642/1321).

Comment: see also, [Best way to kill all child processes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/392022/4279) and [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4789837/4279)

Comment: `ps` is stuck? It would be interesting to see if the folks on _serverfault.com_ had some insight.

Comment: I'd say your server is overloaded.. What configuration does it have? There is "load average: 347.87". OMG. 347?
Also there is a java process that takes.. what.. 2136% CPU.. How many CPU cores do you have there?
8 users and 1444 running processes..
As for me, it does not have resources for every process...

Comment: 'D' status process can't be killed, i tried many times; not `ps` stuck, it is `ps aux or ps ef` stuck terminal. The server has 96 cores with 1000gig memory, it was not server but the terminal stuck, the other process ran well.