# Is there a way to kill uvicorn cleanly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

Is there a way to kill uvicorn cleanly?

I.e., I can type ^C at it, if it is running in the foreground on a terminal. This causes the uvivorn process to die and all of the worker processes to be cleaned up. (I.e., they go away.)

On the other hand, if uvicorn is running in the background without a terminal, then I can't figure out a way to kill it cleanly. It seems to ignore SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGHUP. I can kill it with SIGKILL (i.e. -9), but then the worker processes remain alive, and I have to track all the worker processes down and kill them too. This is not ideal.

I am using uvicorn with CPython 3.7.4, uvivorn version 0.11.2, and FastAPI 0.46.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.3 (Maipo).

Comment: Might be related to #364, could you explain how to run it in the background without a terminal so that I can have a look at it? sigterm and sigint are the only 2 that are "listened" at

Comment: @euri10 There are many ways to run uvicorn in the background without a terminal. One way is to run it, and then to type ^Z to pause it. And then type "bg" to continue it in the background. And then type "exit" to the shell to make the shell and terminal go away.

Alternatively, you could initially run it with "&" on the end of the command line, and elide the ^Z and the "bg". (You still need to type "exit" to the shell to make the shell and terminal go away.)

Comment: @euri10 P.S Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: just tested and I cant reproduce, in a terminal I run uvicorn example:app &! (I'm using zsh so have to use the ! to disown the process or I cant exit the terminal having running jobs) then I close the terminal and I kill -15 pidof uvicorn and it's gone, if you have a way to reproduce happy to try

Comment: Hmmm, weird! Sometimes things behave differently under different shells, but I can't install zsh easily on the computer in question.

It could be a problem specific to Red Hat for some reason, but I wouldn't be able to reproduce that without giving you a Docker image, or something.

Or it might be an issue with specific versions of things that I am running. But I can't easily change those either for various reasons.

In any case, thanks for looking into this!

Comment: How do you run your uvicorn? Are you using uvicornWorkers with gunicorn or pure uvicorn?

Comment: I run it like so: (cd /home/foo; anaconda3-2019.10/bin/uvicorn --workers 20 --port 6700 en_pam_gb:app &> LOG.txt &)

Comment: https://www.uvicorn.org/server-behavior/#graceful-process-shutdown

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's because you're running `uvicorn` as your only server. `uvicorn` **is not a process manager** and, as so, it does not manage its workers life cycle. That's why [they recommend running uvicorn using gunicorn+UvicornWorker](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-with-gunicorn) for production.

That said, you can kill the spawned workers and trigger it's shutdown using the script below:

```bash
$ kill $(pgrep -P $uvicorn_pid)
```

The reason why this works but not the `kill` on the parent pid is because when you `^C` something, the signal is transmitted throughout all of its spawned processes that are attached to the `stdin`.

Comment: I'd like to use this tip of killing background uvicorn workers but when I try to run `kill $(pgrep -P $uvicorn_pid)` I get the following error : 
`pgrep: option requires an argument -- P`
`kill: not enough arguments`

Comment: You need to replace $uvicorn_pid with `uvicorn`'s PID, that's why `pgrep` is complaining about not having an argument.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. 
Still a beginner so got stuck.
Cheers 

Comment: To get uvicorn_pid, You can use something like `uvicorn_pid=pgrep -f 'uvicorn'`

Answer (score 9):

```bash
lsof -i :8000
```

This will check processes using port :8000. If you are using different port for fastAPI then change the port number. I was using postman and python for fastAPI. So check process with python, then copy the PID usually 4-5 numbers.

Then run

```bash
kill -9 PID
```

**Where PID is the PID number you copied**

Comment: Please do not `kill -9` processes, as the pid resources might go corrupt. Proper graceful termination is required to free these resources.

Answer (score 1):

In my case `uvicorn` managed to spawn new processes while `pgrep -P` was killing old ones,
so I decided to kill the whole **process group** at once, just like `^C` does:

```sh
PID="$(pgrep -f example:app)"
if [[ -n "$PID" ]]
then
    PGID="$(ps --no-headers -p $PID -o pgid)"
    kill -SIGINT -- -${PGID// /}
fi
```

Each line explained:

- `pgrep -f example:app` gets the PID of the parent `uvicorn ... example:app`
- `[[ -n "$PID" ]]` checks this PID is not empty, to avoid further steps when `uvicorn` is not running
- `ps --no-headers -p $PID -o pgid` gets PGID (Process Group ID) this PID is part of
- `kill -SIGINT` is similar to polite `^C` (you may use `kill -9` for non-polite instant kill)
- `--` means the next token is a positional argument, not a named option, even if it starts with `-`
- `-${PGID` - negative value lets `kill` know it is PGID, not PID
- `${PGID// /}` removes all spaces `ps` added to PGID to align a column

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to kill all processes having the name 'uvicorn':

```
sudo pkill 'uvicorn'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can try running below command

```
kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep uvicorn  | awk '{print $2}')
```

or

Create and Alias with the command and keep using that command.
For example:

```
alias uvicornprocess="kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep uvicorn  | awk '{print $2}')"
```

Comment: Having to use "kill -9" is not what I'm looking for, unfortunately. "kill -9" is a solution of last resort because something is not quite right.

Answer (score -1):

In case you're running uvicorn in Docker - simply stop the container like this:

```
docker ps # to get the CONTAINER ID
docker stop <CONTAINER ID>
```