# Bash: spawn child processes that quit when parent script quits

Tags: bash, child-process, spawn, spawning

I'd like to spawn several child processes in Bash, but I'd like the parent script to remain running, such that signals send to the parent script also affect the spawned children processes.

This doesn't do that:

`parent.bash`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

spawnedChildProcess1 &
spawnedChildProcess2 &
spawnedChildProcess3 &
```

`parent.bash` ends immediately, and the spawned processes continue running independently of it.

Comment: Only signals sent to the parent's process group will also be sent to the child processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wait` to have the parent process wait for all the children to exit.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

spawnedChildProcess1 &
spawnedChildProcess2 &
spawnedChildProcess3 &

wait
```

Keyboard signals are sent to the entire process group, so typing <kbd>Ctl-c</kbd> will kill the children and the parent.

Comment: However, `kill -s 19 \`pgrep -f "parent.bash"\`` doesn't send that signal to the children processes. (Maybe this is a separate question.)

Comment: That only kills the parent process, not the whole process group. `kill -INT -$(pgrep -f "parent.bash")` A negative process ID means to kill the process group.

Comment: Found answer: "[What's the best way to send a signal to all members of a process group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15139734/1429450)."

Comment: Your command returns an error that the negative number doesn't correspond to a process.

Comment: It should work if the process group hasn't finished.

Comment: It's the same as the answers in the question you linked to.

Answer (score 8):

If you want your parent to not exit immediately after spawning its children, then as Barmar told you, use `wait`.

Now, if you want your child processes to die when the parent exits, then send them a `SIGTERM` (or any other) signal just before exiting:

```
kill 0
```

(0 is a special PID that means "every process in the parent's process group")

If the parent may exit unexpectedly (e.g. upon receiving a signal, because of a `set -u` or `set -e`, etc.) then you can use `trap` to send the `TERM` signal to the child just before exiting:

```
trap 'kill 0' EXIT
```

[edit] In conclusion, this is how you should write your parent process:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
trap 'kill 0' EXIT
...
spawnedChildProcess1 &
spawnedChildProcess2 &
spawnedChildProcess3 &
...
wait
```

That way no need to send your signal to a negative process ID since this won't cover all the cases when your parent process may die.

Comment: Without `wait` the parent will exit immediately after spawning the children, and it will then kill all the children.

Comment: @Barmar Well, the title says that child processes must quit when parent quits, not that the parent script must quit when children quit.

Comment: The first line: "I'd like the parent script to remain running"

Comment: @Barmar, OK got it, but `wait` is only part of the answer.

Comment: Yeah,we each answered half the question.