# How to make Bash background command exit when parent exits?

Tags: bash

I would like `python3` command to exit when parent exits (after 10 seconds).

```sh
#! /bin/bash

sudo bash -c "python3 screen-buttons.py &"

sleep 10

printf "%s\n" "Done"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash: spawn child processes that quit when parent script quits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66537526/bash-spawn-child-processes-that-quit-when-parent-script-quits)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to know the pid you want to kill, one way or the other.

```
#!/bin/bash

# assuming screen-buttons.py does not output anything to stdout
pid=$(sudo bash -c 'python3 screen-buttons.py & echo $!') 
sleep 10
kill "$pid"
```

If screen-buttons.py outputs something to stdout, save the pid to a file and read it from parent.

But it looks like you want to implement a timeout. If so see.. `timeout` utility.

To kill all descendant see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124127/kill-all-descendant-processes

And anyway, why call bash and background in child process? Just call what you want to call.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python3 screen-buttons.py &
pid=$!
sleep 10
sudo kill "$pid"
```

and anyway:

```
sudo timeout 10 python3 screen-buttons.py
```

Comment: This also has the problem that the `python3` process is run under `sudo` (so probably owned by root) so the calling script (probably not owned by root) can't kill it.

Comment: Thanks Kamil... `screen-buttons.py` doesn't output anything... it is essentially a loop listening to GPIO triggers. When I run command, `pid` has no value.

Comment: I guess the loop inside Python script means `echo $!` is never called...

Comment: `I guess the loop inside Python script means echo $! is never called` You guess seems wrong - the python script is run in the background with `&`, it's irrelevant what it does. `When I run command, pid has no value` Och right - quoting is wrong. Try now. But why are you are calling `bash` at all?